# Setting a result returned from rest api to a template variable in Meteor

Tags: javascript, rest, meteor

I am learning how to use Meteor and I am trying to connect to google map api and return json
using meteor.http.get.The following code works fine and i can set the template variable test equal to the json returned and view it(i want to use this for learning purposes for now):

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        getGoogleMaps: function () {
            this.unblock();
            return Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
                {params:{address:"8-10 Broadway, London SW1H 0BG,United Kingdom",
                    sensor:false}});
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.main.test=function(){ return Session.get("response");}
    Meteor.call("getGoogleMaps", function(error, results) {
        Session.set("response", results.content); 
   });
}
```

But the following methods to assign the json returned to the test template variable do not work:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    var response;

    Meteor.call("getResponses", function(error, results) {
            response= results.content;         
    });  

   Template.main.test=function(){ return response;}
}
```

This does not work either:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.call("getResponses", function(error, results) {
            Template.main.test= results.content;        
    });  
}
```

Why do the last two methods do not work? What would be the most appropriate method to set a template variable from a result returned from a rest api?

Comment: this answer your question, I think the first way is the appropriate way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533637/meteor-http-get-issue-with-twitter-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method sets the value, but by the time the response is received from the server, the client has already rendered the template so you aren't seeing the result.  This kind of timing problem is a common issue when first getting started with asynchronous javascript and its one of the main reasons that Meteor's reactivity is so appealing.

The third method has the same timing issue as the second but it also is setting a template helper to a non-function value so that is invalid.

The first method works as you'd expect due to Meteor's reactivity.  This line:

```
Template.main.test=function(){ return Session.get("response");}
```

...registers a dependency on Session.get('response'). When the response is finally received from the server, the call to Session.set('response') triggers a recomputation of all dependencies so the template gets rendered again with the received value.

You can see this more explicitly by doing something like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.main.rendered = function () {
    console.log('[main] rendered');
  };

  Template.main.helpers({
    test: function () { 
      console.log("[main] 'test' helper executed");
      return Session.get("response");
    }
  });

  Meteor.call("getGoogleMaps", function(error, results) {
    console.log("[main] response received");
    Session.set("response", results.content); 
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the thorough explanation, the code above really helped understanding this