# Meteor trying to get twitter user location

Tags: twitter, meteor

My code:

```
var authkey = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog", 
      oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg", 
      oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D", 
      oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
      oauth_timestamp=""+(new Date().getTime()/1000).toFixed(0)+"", 
      oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb", 
      oauth_version="1.0"";

var result =  Meteor.http.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json",{headers:{Authorization : authkey});
```

Here's the error:

Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
server/accounts.js:81:50: Unexpected identifier

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Line 81 points to the authkey.

Comment: Would you please post the error?

Comment: Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: failed [400] {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Comment: You need to OAauth sign the request.

Comment: can you show me how to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example [on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533637/meteor-http-get-issue-with-twitter-api?rq=1).

Basically, you need to do the following:

- **Generate your oauth keys on twitter for your app**
- **Fill in those keys into a variable, such as the authkey variable shown in that SO post**
- **Pass that variable in using the object that includes {headers: {Authorization: authkey}}**

There are details for creating the **[oauth signature on Twitter's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures)**.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have generated my keys on twitter. I can't seem to get the get authkey working though. I followed the format on the post you linked and it's giving me an Unexpected identifier error.

Comment: @shinonchan - would you please post your updated code and full error details?

Comment: @ShinonChan as from your updated post, seems like you have syntax error, Might be following - you did not put quotes on some variable value. Further, can you post little snippet of code where error is getting if above does not solve problem

Comment: i think i fixed the syntax error. so the oauth consumer key and secret are the ones from my twitter dev account, the token is from the user login. how do i get the oauth signature??

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the link to Twitters documentation https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures.